# Getting "name" is not defined error

Tags: python, python-3.x, nameerror

I have an assignment for my class that is getting to be a headache for me.
Define a class called Car with the following attributes:

Total Odometer Miles

Speed in miles per hour

Driver Name

Sponsor

The total odometer miles and speed should be initialized to zero.

Create a list of 20 unique vehicles with random (or real (Links to an external site.)Links to an external site.) driver and sponsor names.

Your main program should simulate the progress of the vehicles in the race. Every simulated minute, the vehicles pick a new random speed between 1 and 120, and their odometer miles are updated every minute using this equation:

odometer_miles = odometer_miles + speed * time 
Since speed is in miles per hour, time should be in hours as well (1 minute is 1/60th of an hour).

I think maybe my understanding of using `def` is off. As the title says when I run my program it says

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/darrellanddawn/Documents/Nascar.py", line 63, in 
>       main()
>
> File "/Users/darrellanddawn/Documents/Nascar.py", line 57, in main
>       racers()
>
> NameError: name 'racers' is not defined

Any suggestions or explanations as to why I am getting this error?

```
start = True

#Car and drivers

class Car:
    def racers():
        global miles
        miles = 0
        speed = 0
        drivers = {'00' : 'Van Hellsing', '01' : 'Vlad Dragul', '02' :'Lightening McSeen',
'03' : 'Viktor Frankenstein', '04' : 'Richy Rich', '05' : 'Lynn Steely',
'06' : 'Roscoe Bautista','07' : 'Matt Pilling', '08' :'Fredric Montrose', 
'09' : 'Ward Clutts', '10' :'Miles Bruck', '11': 'Darrin Isakson', '12' :'Chauncey Speno', 
'13' : 'Billie Coghill', '14' : 'Donn Lusher', '15' : 'Vaughn Naugle', '16' :'Patrick Climer',
'17' : 'Jerome Harring', '18' : 'Carlo Bohanon', '19' : 'Brian Coggins'}
    sponsers = {'00' : 'Pepesi', '01' : 'Coke', '02' : 'Pensoil',
'03' : 'Wal-Mart', '04' : 'Exxon', '05' : 'Shell',
'06' : 'Food Lion','07' : 'McDonalds', '08' :'Ubisoft', 
'09' : 'Taco Bell', '10' :'Good Year', '11': 'Apple', '12' :'Microsoft', 
'13' : 'Lowes', '14' : 'Home Depot', '15' : 'Save-A-Lot', '16' :'Sprint',
'17' : 'Verison', '18' : 'Virgin Mobile', '19' : 'Huggies'}

def race():
    import random
    global speed
    winner = False
    time = 0

    while not winner:
        speed = random.randint(1,120)
        time = + 1
        miles = miles + (speed / 60) * time

def win(driver, sponser):
    if miles == 500:
        winner = True

        while winner:
            print('The winner is: ', drivers, sponsers)


def stop():
    print('Thank you for watching the UAT 500!')
    import sys
    sys.exit(0)

def main():
    Car
    racers()
    race()
    win()
    stop()

while start:
    main()
```

Comment: `racers()` is only defined inside the `Car` class, not inside the `main()` method

Comment: Please post the error you get un your question and indicate what line gives the error

Comment: It seems you misunderstand `global`. It just says that you want to modify the variable with that name in the global scope. It doesn't create a global variable. Try to implement it without globals that should solve that problem and the next "x" problems that arise.

Comment: @MSeifert So global is not used in order for a variable to be used in multiple functions? Going to try your suggestions but want to make sure that I understand. My 5th week learning python but they aren't giving us much to go on as far as examples, books, videos, etc.

Comment: @GrayCygnus, did an edit to show error and lines. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Car():

    #initializes properties of the car
    def __init__(self,driver_name,sponsor,car_name):
        self.miles = 0 # self refers to car instance
        self.speed = 0
        self.driver_name = driver_name
        self.sponsor = sponsor
        self.car_name = car_name

    # changes the cars speed to a new speed
    def update_speed(self, new_speed):
        self.speed = new_speed

    #calculates the total distance traveled
    def distance_traveled(self, elapsed_time):
        self.miles += self.speed * elapsed_time


def race(car1,car2,distance):

    elapsed_time = 0.0
    _time = 0.01
    won = False

    while not won:

        #updates speed of the car to a random int between 100 and 150
        car1.update_speed(random.randint(100,150))
        #print("{} speed: {}".format(car1.car_name,car1.speed))
        #updates the distance traveled with increments of _time
        car1.distance_traveled(_time)
        #print("{} miles: {}".format(car1.car_name,car1.miles))

        car2.update_speed(random.randint(100,150))
        # print("{} speed: {}".format(car2.car_name,car2.speed))
        car2.distance_traveled(_time)
        # print("{} miles: {}".format(car2.car_name,car2.miles))

        if car2.miles >= distance:
            print("{} is the winner!!".format(car2.driver_name))
            won = True

        if car1.miles >= distance:
            print("{} is the winner!!".format(car1.driver_name))
            won = True

        elapsed_time += _time
        #print("elapsed time: {}".format(elapsed_time))

def main():
    #instantiates two car objects
    car1 = Car("Van Hellsing","Pepsi","car1")
    car2 = Car("Vlad Dragul","Coke","car2")

    # races the two cars
    race(car1,car2,10)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

hi, here are some suggestions...

1. avoid using the `global` keyword instead use the `return` statement
2. import modules at the top of your code
3. create functions that accomplish a single task
4. change racers function to the `__init__` method
5. drivers not be initialized in the Car class because it is not specific to any car

Comment: Thank you very much! Was trying to avoid global but instructor gives minimal help and this was all I could think to do.